# C++: Cast object to array

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, operator-overloading

I'm writing a matrix class and I want to be able to cast a fixed sized matrix to an fixed sized double array. Although, I have troubles implementing the appropriate cast operator. What I've implemented so far does not work:

```
template<unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Matrix
{
    typedef double (&ArrayType)[M][N];
public:
     operator ArrayType();
}


Matrix<3,3> mat1;
double matArr[3][3];
matArr =  mat1;
```

> error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘sfz::Matrix<3u, 3u>’ to
>   ‘double [3][3]’

Casting the matrix explicitly causes another error:

> error: ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type ‘double [3][3]’

Is there no way to implement the syntax i want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assign arrays, ever. Live with it.

To make your function work, you could make a *reference*:

```
double (&ar)[3][3] = mat1;
```

Alternatively, you could *wrap* your naked array in something like `std::array<std::array<double, M>, N>` and return *that* by value. That's why wrappers like `std::array` exist – they allow you to treat arrays like values. The same trick has worked in C since day one (putting an array inside a struct), but it's actually nice and readable in C++:

```
typedef typename std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> type;
operator type() const { return internal_array; }
```

Comment: Whats the difference between double (&ar)[3][3] and double ar[3][3]?

Comment: @Paranaix: The first is a reference, the second isn't.